# How to find *.css files for further processing but ignore all *.min.css files?

Tags: batch-file

I want to use yui compressor to automatically and recursively compress my js/css files with a command similar to the following:

```
for %%f in (*.css) do (
    java -jar d:\projects\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o %%~nf.min.css --charset utf8 --nomunge %%~nf.css
)
```

However, the problem is, if I use loop above, when I update my css/js files later and run this script again, a lot of files ending with **.min.min.css** and **.min.min.js** will be produced.

How to find *.css files for compression with ignoring all *.min.css files?

**Edit**:
after following @Magoo's instructions for recursive version

```
D:\bak\static>compress.bat
java.io.FileNotFoundException: bakstaticstyleSet.min.css:\bak\static\styleSet.cs
s (文件名、目录名或卷标语法不正确。)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.YUICompressor.main(YUICompressor.ja
va:208)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.yahoo.platform.yui.compressor.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:21)
```

The Chinese sentence above means **incorrect filename, directory name, or volumn name**.

This seems to be a bug of yui compressor, rather than the batch scripts. But is there any change that I can do the recursion in a waylike `cd` to a directory, do something, and then `cd ..` back.

**Edit2:**

I run the modified script, it does compress all css files recursively. However, some files generated have wrong names. Examples:

```
check_input.js   --->   CHECK_~1.min.js
jsAddress.js     --->   JSADDR~1.min.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.css" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:".min.css"'
 ) DO (
  ECHO(java -jar d:\projects\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o %%~nf.min.css --charset utf8 --nomunge %%~nf.css
)

GOTO :EOF
```

This should cure your problem.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The `java` command is merely `echo`ed - remove the `echo(` **after verification** to activate.

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.css" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:".min.css"'
 ) DO (
  ECHO(java -jar d:\projects\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o "%%~dpnf.min.css" --charset utf8 --nomunge "%%~dpnf.css"
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Revision for recursion. Assumes `java` understands quoted-filenames. The quotes are not required if the path/filenames do not contain separators (like <kbd>Space</kbd> for instance)

---

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN (
 'dir /s /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.css" ^|findstr /v /i /L /c:".min.css"'
 ) DO (
  PUSHD "%%~sdpf"
  ECHO !cd!
  ECHO(java -jar d:\projects\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar -o "%%~snf.min.css" --charset utf8 --nomunge "%%~snf.css"
  popd
)

GOTO :EOF
```

Revision to attempt to solve problem with recursion.

I strongly suspect that the problem is related to unicode which `cmd` doesn't handle well.

This version uses a `pushd/popd` frame to change the current directory to the curent target. I can't test unicode, so perhaps using the shortname (invoked by the `~s` operator) may be of assistance.

I included the `echo !cd!` simply to display the current directory, gratuitously using the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` that I'd  erroneously left in the original batch. I wasn't using it (it's part of my batch template) and it can be omitted (but must be there to use the `!var!` expansion syntax)

---

Supplemental information which I hope is useful.

By defauly, every file and directory has two names - the "long" and the "short" name. The "short" name is generated from the "long" name using an algorithm that isn't relevant, but what it aims to do is create an alternative name following the original `DOS` 8.3 naming scheme - 8 ANSI characters for the name and 3 for the extension, separated by a dot. Naturally, if the name already complied with the 8.3 convention, no extra name was created.

You can see these name by executing **dir /x** from the prompt.

In batch, the `FOR` loop can extract parts of a filename. if `%%a` is the metavariable (the variable controlling the loop) then `%%~pa` will produce the directory ("**P**ath) part only. Similarly, `D` is used for the **D**rive, `N` is used for the **N**ame, `X` is used for the e**X**tension and there are others. See `FOR /?|more` from the prompt for more docco.

To access the `short` name - which is designed to be guaranteed-ANSI-8.3 - you use the `~s` modifier, so `%%~sna` means the **S**hort **N**ame of the file `"%%a"`.

Unicode is a later invention. I was hoping that using the short names would allow `cmd` to process the files as it wasn't really designed for unicode.

Since the name of the generated file is `"%%~snf.css"` then this means the **s**hort **n**ame from `%%f` + ".css", and the pushd/popd frame actually changes the current directory to the real directory by using its short name. Therefore, we hane no need of a directory name when generating the new file (it therefore defaults to the current directory) and the name of the file is the short name because the destination filespec includes the `s` modifier. Removing the `s` and setting it to `"%%~nf.css"` would thus use the original long name - and that's probably safe if the original **file**name is not unicode.

Comment: Fantastic! Just one further question, what if I want to recursively process all files under subdirectories?

Comment: almost there. But some files with wired names got generated. I'm wondering if it's also related to unicode. See above.